# Putting someone's question on hold is ultimately generating load on Stack Overflow server

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, on-hold

Suppose someone is a new user on this site. He asks a question that is not of good quality or he has not shown good effort/research work for whatever  reason. I see that after a few hours someone has put his question on hold. Then he can ask the same question by creating a new account and user name.

Hence it can generate an overload on the community sever.

Comment: ...whereupon the new question will be closed, too, the accounts will be merged, and the user will be under constant scrutiny by other members with mod flags in their quivers for the next few weeks. What exactly are you asking or trying to discuss?

Comment: I am trying to discuss.If someone is new here and he has not asked question of Good quality.Then we should not put his question on Hold directly. **Best Solution:** We should show right way to do it first.

Comment: I agree. Instead, these bad questions should just be **deleted** outright. Problem solved.

Comment: So your argument is that we should not put questions on hold when they are asked by new users? Sorry, that isn't going to happen. The whole point of putting a question on hold is to show them the right way to do it.

Comment: That is good.. but user also cant answer his question which is marked as hold,at lest we should give him chance to answer his question.

Comment: We could prevent new users from asking questions altogether.

Comment: With regard to load on the servers: [Wikipedia has an essay on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_worry_about_performance), which includes the choice quote "*...don't go running around screaming "teh servers, teh servers!!!" as an excuse to not do stuff, that's stupid.*"

Comment: @s.singh: So your suggestion isn't *actually* about load on servers at all, right? It's about how we respond to bad questions. That topic has been done to death here.

Comment: How ironic...this question was put on hold. Well, in light of the ensuing discussion, I would like to strongly recommend to s.singh that he *not* create a new account and repost this question.

Comment: I will not do that. It was a discussion and I got my ans very well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hold reasons contain information to help the user to improve the question. If the question is reworked to fit the site format, it can be reopened.

If the user asks a new question, it will be put on hold (and eventually closed) like the first one. If it becomes a pattern of behavior, the mods have methods of preventing and/or quickly dealing with future abuse.

The best method to deal with bad questions is to vote them down, vote to hold/close, and (optionally) offer improvement tips to the asker via comments.

Comment: Thanks George for Clarification. Is there any chance to close their account?

Comment: @s.singh If multiple "different" users post the same question over and over again, their accounts will likely be merged and their IP potentially be put on question ban

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that this sort of thing happens anywhere near often enough to put any noticeable load on the server. It would have to happen many times per minute to create noticeable additional server load, and I doubt if it happens as often as once a day.

There's really no point in creating a new account and asking again. As others have pointed out, if the user asks the question again the same way, it will be closed again for the same reason(s) - and it won't go unnoticed that it's identical to a recently closed question. Also, keep in mind that closed questions would be very unlikely to have received any help if they hadn't been closed, for the very same reasons why they *were* closed. So reposting isn't going to accomplish anything positive.

If, on the other hand, the user wants *improve* the question and resubmit it, then there's no need to create a new account. Having a question put on hold and closed doesn't automatically suspend your privilege to ask questions; question bans are only imposed if there's a pattern of asking bad questions (for example, repeatedly creating new accounts to resubmit questions identical to ones that have been closed would probably do it...) If you want to resubmit an improved question, you can do it with the same account. In fact, you can (and should) do it without even writing a new post; just edit the original question that was put on hold, and if the problems that caused it to be put on hold are adequately addressed by the improvements, it will be reopened.

Putting questions on hold accomplishes exactly what you called the "Best Solution" - helping users who ask poor quality questions learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: ***NO NO NO NO NO NO NO*** don't tell people to repost questions! **Edit** the on-hold question, and it will be put in a Reopen Votes review queue.

Comment: @Doorknob Okay, okay! I was just making the point that it's silly to create a new account if you're going to *improve* the original question, because you can do that with the same account. But, I changed the answer to make it clear that the improvements should be made by editing the original question. And you'll be happy to see that I edited my answer rather than reposting. ;)